# git delete last stash commit only

Tags: git, git-stash

When I have more stashes than one, sometimes I need to drop one or two before the last one:

```
> git stash
stash@{0}: WIP on 0.9.1: e59f763 UPDATE deploy script UPDATE requirements
stash@{1}: WIP on dev: c9f86fb ADD index view ADD return view ADD welcome
```

In this case I want to drop `@{0}`. If I `git stash pop` I got into merge conflicts that I have to solve manually, maybe not only once, to get rid of the stashed commit.

Usually, I create another branch:

```
git checkout -b temp  
git stash pop
# solve merge-conflicts
git checkout branch_for_stash@{1}
git stash pop
```

Is there any (`git`) command to remove the last, or even any stashed commit?

Comment: git stash drop?

Comment: it is exactly that one

Comment: Cool, glad it worked

Answer (score 12):

It appears the the question was already answered in the comments. For future reference, here's the corresponding documentation for [`git stash drop`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#git-stash-drop-q--quietltstashgt):

> Remove a single stash entry from the list of stash entries. When no <stash> is given, it removes the latest one. i.e. stash@{0}, otherwise <stash> must be a valid stash log reference of the form stash@{<revision>}.

So to drop just the stash entry `stash@{1}`, the command would look like:

```
$ git stash drop stash@{1}
```

Note that the number in the reference is a count from the top of the list, so dropping `stash@{1}` twice in a row will remove `stash@{1}` and then what previously was `stash@{2}`.

This works equally for the `git stash apply` and `git stash pop` commands, i.e.:

```
$ git stash apply stash@{1}
$ git stash pop stash@{1}
```